# Running an inference with Tensorflow Lite model in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run an inference on a TFLite model.

My Tensorflow model specification is:

```
Input Shape(Int) - (None, 100, 12) [Batch Size will be 1 while inferencing, So, Input will be 1x100x12] 
Output Shape(Float) - (None, 3) [If Batch Size is 1, output will be 1x3]
```

I followed the steps outlined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android) to import the model through the UI`(New -> Other -> Tensorflow Lite Model)`.

After that, I used the sample code provided from model specification -

```
HarClassification model = HarClassification.newInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

// Creates inputs for reference.
TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 100, 12}, DataType.FLOAT32);

//inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

// Runs model inference and gets result.
HarClassification.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

Log.i("Tensorflow","Ran successfully");

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close();
```

**Please note that, I'm not trying to inference an image. I prefer to inference an integer array.**

***Things I've tried:***

I understand that I have two options of manipulating the `TensorBuffer`.

1. `loadBuffer`
2. `loadArray`

I cannot figure out how to correctly provide input of shape`(1x100x12)` through `loadBuffer`.
`loadArray` cannot seem to take `int[1][100][12]` as input.

Please let me know a correct way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/blob/master/tensorflow_lite_support/java/src/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/tensorbuffer/TensorBuffer.java#L156

You can get a ByteBuffer from the getBuffer method of the inputFeature0.

You can manipulate the ByteBuffer object to fill up the value.

Or you can create a TensorBuffer with an array as well. You can find samples from
https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/blob/86687d36d93ad5a2e16c0da0ddb55adc6d1c7af1/tensorflow_lite_support/java/src/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/tensorbuffer/TensorBuffer.java#L87